# New DTO or Field Selector for API?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I am working on new API, but I am stuck with the choice for enabling `Projection` support.

my Entity `User` contains some properties and have some relationships too.

What should be the preferred approach for API?

**Approach1**

`myApi.com/User/Fields="Id,Name,Email"`

it returns my `UserDTO` with just populating `Id`,`Name`,`Email` and rest properties are null (I can further ignore the null before serializing JSON to send over the wire)

**Approach2**

`myApi.com/User/GetCustomPropertiesABC"`

it returns my `UserCustomABCDTO` . This Model contains just three properties for `Id`, `Name`, `Email`.

**My question**

I personally feel Approach 1 gives more Reuse quotient to API, Every time new selector required in Approach 2 will need to create a New DTO, But what is standard as per REST principles?

Answer (score 0):

well, you could use ODATA for this, it would be perfect for it actually : http://www.odata.org/

Or, you could create an endpoint which accepts a request like your Approach 1 and returns dynamic. This way you don't have to worry about creating DTOs, you just create a new dynamic object, add whatever properties are required and return just that.

This keeps the returned entity small as it avoids who knows how many null or empty properties which don't really add anything useful.